# Blackberry 10 simulator showing blank screen windows

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

Hi i have installed latest blackberry 10 Simulator (BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer-BB10_2_1-1925-Win-201312191822) .After installing when i click on controller i am getting a blank white screen as shown in bellow screenshot.I am using windows 8.0 Enterprise.What may be the issue?Thanks in advance.

[image: BB10Emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the exact same problem.
Upgrading from a generic graphic driver with OpenGL 1.1 to a specific driver that enabled OpenGL 2.1 solved the problem.

You can check which OpenGL version do you have with this software: http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.php

I had to manually force the installation of an older Vista driver in Windows 8.1 for my Intel 4 Series graphic card. Since Intel does not offer official drivers for Win8 and Win8.1 I had to:

1) modify the .inf file inside the latest official graphic card drivers to enable the installation for unsupported Windows.
I changed this part:

```
[Manufacturer]
%Intel%   = IntelGfx, NTamd64.5.1, NTamd64.6.0, NTamd64.6.2 

[IntelGfx.NTamd64.5.1]
; no install on XP

[IntelGfx.NTamd64.6.2]
; no install on Win8

[IntelGfx.NTamd64.6.0]
```

to this:

```
[Manufacturer]
%Intel%   = IntelGfx, NTamd64 

[IntelGfx.NTamd64]
```

2) I allowed installation of unsigned drivers with these commands in cmd:

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions DISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

3) I installed the Intel graphic drivers, then after a reboot I re-enabled signed drivers with these commands:

```
bcdedit -set loadoptions ENABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
```

4) Make sure that Windows Update does not automatically install the newer signed generic graphic card drivers that will overwrite you custom Vista drivers. Just mark as hidden the update as soon as it appears in Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the graphics driver for your video card. Older drivers for ATI video cards have this issue.